# Is there a safe and secure API for accessing multiple financial institutions simply to get account balances?

Tags: plaid

I want to create a document or small program to compile all of my finances automatically in one place, but it seems a lot of the banks don't have easy access to an API where I can pull these account balances. Is there a solution already built for this kind of thing that doesn't take your data? I've heard of Plaid, but I've also heard that they are notorious for stealing all of your data.

Answer (score 0):

There is not really a practical way for developers to do this via API without using Plaid or a service like it. You can see Plaid's [data handling policies here](https://plaid.com/how-we-handle-data/) and its [data management tool here](https://my.plaid.com/). I work at Plaid so I may be biased, but I'm not aware of any company operating in this space that has policies or tools more favorable to end-users than Plaid's -- for example, Plaid provides a data deletion tool for end users and doesn't sell user data (even in anonymized form).

Comment: Huh, but (and not meaning to attack or anything here) didn't you guys just settle in this lawsuit about violating data privacy laws? https://www.wifr.com/2022/01/25/plaid-must-pay-58-million-users-venmo-credit-karma-other-apps/

Comment: Yes. A settlement is an agreement to end litigation -- it is not an admission of guilt and doesn't indicate that both parties agree with the claims. Plaid settled the suit to avoid the cost and burden associated with protracted litigation. The claims raised in the lawsuit do not reflect our practices. We do not sell user data and never have.